# Selenium webdriver automatic testing data PHP

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I have question about use Selenium webdriver. I need put data into form on website. But I don't know how to load many data.

For example:

I have database with name some person and a need put one by one name into form on website and submit it. But Selenium webdriver doesn't work with database.

I am using PHP

Comment: " I dont know how" stackoverflow is not tutorial but code review or solve your errors. If you post your code which not work you can give any answer. If you don't know how load data read the manual or any guide.

Comment: We can connect to database using PHP and get the data . And We can send that data to browser using selenium webdriver. There is lot of tutorials available online for free. Go through it first. And if you face any problems then put it here..